# Prove $(a_n)$ has a lower bound $> -1$ if $a_n \to 0$ and $a_n > -1$

Tags: real-analysis

$(a_n)$ is a sequence with $(a_n) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $\forall n \: a_n>-1$, $a_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty $, can I prove that $\exists q>-1$ such that $a_n \ge q\:$ for all n?

Comment: Where are you having trouble?

Comment: I was trying to approach it using contradiction:  
Assume the opposite: $ \forall q >-1 \:\: \exists a_n < q $, but then I was stuck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. By letting $\epsilon=1/2$, by the definition of limit, it follows that there is $N$ such that for all $n> N$,
$$|a_n|<\epsilon=1/2\implies a_n> -1/2.$$
Show that $q:=\min\{-1/2,a_1,a_2, \dots,a_N\}>-1$ and $a_n\geq q$ for all $n\geq 1$.

Comment: if $a_n$ does not tend to 0, is it right that it can no longer be proved $(a_n)$ has a lower bound $> -1$?

Comment: You can find such $q$ as soon as $(a_n)\to L$ and $L>-1$. For example the property holds even if $(a_n)\to -1/2$.

Comment: so if $a_n$ is divergent, such q cannot be found?

Comment: Actually it suffices that $\liminf_{n\to +\infty} a_n=L>-1$.